# Dataframe - Converting entire column from str object to datetime object - TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to convert values in entire column from `strings` to `datetime` objects, but I can't accomplish it with this code which works on solo strings i.e. (if I add .iloc[] and specify the index):

```
price_df_higher_interval['DateTime'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(price_df_higher_interval['DateTime'],
                                                                     '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Also I would like to ommit looping through the dataframe, but I don't know if that won't be necessery.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pd.to_datetime` function.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"str_date": ["2023-01-01 12:13:21", "2023-01-02 13:10:24 "]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["str_date"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

```
df.dtypes
str_date            object
date        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```